# Getting empty Java List after converting from RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm creating a RDD in 1st part of the application, then converting it to a list using rdd.collect().

But for some reason the list size is coming as 0 in the second part of the application , while the RDD from which I'm creating the list is not empty.Even rdd.toArray() is giving empty list.

Below is my program.

```
 public class Query5kPids implements Serializable{

 List<String> ListFromS3 = new ArrayList<String>();

 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Spark-Cassandra Integration");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "12.16.193.19");
        conf.setMaster("yarn-cluster");

        SparkConf conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkAutomation").setMaster("yarn-cluster");

        Query5kPids app1 = new Query5kPids(conf1);
        app1.run1(file);

        Query5kPids app = new Query5kPids(conf);
        System.out.println("Both RDD has been generated");
        app.run();

}

private void run() throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        query(sc);
        sc.stop();
}

private void run1(File file) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {
         JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
         getData(sc,file);
         sc.stop();

}

    private void getData(JavaSparkContext sc, File file) {

         JavaRDD<String> Data = sc.textFile(file.toString());
         System.out.println("RDD Count is " + Data.count());
         // here it prints some count value
         ListFromS3 = Data.collect();
         // ListFromS3 = Data.toArray();

    }
     private void query(JavaSparkContext sc) {

         System.out.println("RDD Count is " + ListFromS3.size());
         // Prints 0
         // So cant convert the list to RDD
         JavaRDD<String> rddFromGz = sc.parallelize(ListFromS3);

    }


  }
```

NOTE -> In the actual program , the RDD and List is of type.

```
List<UserSetGet> ListFromS3 = new ArrayList<UserSetGet>();
JavaRDD<UserSetGet> Data = new ....
```

where UserSetGet is a Pojo , With Setter and getter methods, and its Serializable.

Comment: Can you please fix the code formatting? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app1.run1` puts the RDD contents into `app1.ListFromS3`. Then you look at `app.ListFromS3`, which is empty. `app1.ListFromS3` and `app.ListFromS3` are fields on two different objects. Setting one does not set the other.

I think you meant `ListFromS3` to be `static`, meaning it belongs to the `Query5kPids` class, not to a particular instance. Like this:

```
static List<String> ListFromS3 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel , I cant believe I did a silly mistake like this. Appreciated :)